# Cannot resolve the symbols 'textview' and 'imageview' in onBindViewHolder method inside RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android programming. I was learning about the implementation of **RecyclerView**, to make a list of app icons along with their names, in a grid layout. The following is the code of my `CustomAdapter`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    ArrayList appNames;
    ArrayList appImages;
    Context context;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList appNames, ArrayList appImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appNames = appNames;
        this.appImages = appImages;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // infalte the item Layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // set the data in items
        holder.name.setText(appNames.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageResource(appImages.get(position));
        // implement setOnClickListener event on item view.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // open another activity on item click
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", (Bundle) appImages.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                context.startActivity(intent); // start Intent
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appNames.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // init the item view's
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;
        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // get the reference of item view's
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the textview `name` and imageview `image` shows, cannot be resolved, inside `onBindViewHolder`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please add the line where you initialize the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder
```

change to

```
onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder  holder
```

also change class declaration

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
...
```

Comment: It shows `Method does not override method from its superclass`

Comment: public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
```

to

```
public class CustomAdapter extends CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder
```

This will lead you to change the onBindViewHolder signature also.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
```

Now the viewObjects can be resolved as they are part of the ViewHolder.